# If item has class change css of another

Tags: jquery, html, css, conditional-statements

So I have a unordered list as my menu. I have it setup so that whenever I click a menu item, that menu item then gets the class "active" added to it, and any other list item with that class has it removed. This part works fine. Now, I have an arrow that is absolute position and i simply want to change the "top" style depending on what class has the "active" class. It is only checking when the site initially loads, so won't change placement when another list item gets the "active" class. NOTE: The ".active-item" is the arrow.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.nav .nav-items li').click(function () {
        $('.nav .nav-items li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

});

if ($('.nav .nav-items .nav-dash').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.nav .nav-items .active-item').css('top', '30px');
};

if ($('.nav .nav-items .nav-sales').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.nav .nav-items .active-item').css('top', '90px');
}; etc...
```

Comment: `.removeAttr('style')` will only remove styles that are placed directly in the HTML

Comment: And  what problem are you having? I don't see an issue, is this not working for you?

Comment: The "top" element is not changing when I click another list item.

Comment: It is just staying at the '30px'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must place the arrow positioning code in the click() handler for menu item click event if you want the position to be changed on clicks and not only on page load.

Comment: Thank you! Seems pretty obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do it in your stylesheet. Its going to be a LOT faster:

```
.nav-items > .active .active-item{
    top: 0px;
}
.nav-items > .active.nav-sales .active-item{
    top: 30px;
}
.nav-items > .active.nav-sales .active-item{
    top: 90px;
} 
/* etc */
```

The this way, you don't have to add nearly as much code as you would otherwise need.

But if you *really* need to do it in JavaScript this should do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkNavItems(){
        if ($('.nav .nav-items .nav-dash').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.nav .nav-items .active-item').removeAttr('style');
            $('.nav .nav-items .active-item').css('top', '30px');
        };

        if ($('.nav .nav-items .nav-sales').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.nav .nav-items .active-item').removeAttr('style');
            $('.nav .nav-items .active-item').css('top', '90px');
        }; etc...
    }

    $('.nav .nav-items li').click(function () {
        $('.nav .nav-items li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        checkNavItems();
    });

    checkNavItems(); 
});
```

However, your code is not doing what you think its doing. In the first place, you are removing the style for all the active-item nodes, and then setting the top for all the active-item nodes. I'm guessing you're trying to clear out all the previously set styles and set the style only on this one. This situation is EASIER to manage with CSS but, again here is JS that should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeStyles ={
        'nav-dash': {
            'top': '30px'
        }, 
        'nav-sales': {
            'top' : '90px'
        }
        //ETC
    } 

    function checkNavItems(){
        var active = $('.nav .nav-items .active'),
            activeItem = $('.nav .nav-items .active .active-item');
            inactiveItem = $('.nav .nav-items .not(.active) .active-item');
        activeItem.removeAttr('style');

        for (key in activeStyles) {
            if (activeStyles.hasOwnProperty(key) && active.hasClass(key)) {
                activeItem.css(activeStyles[key]);
                break; //Only do it once
            };
        };
    }

    $('.nav .nav-items li').click(function () {
        $('.nav .nav-items li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        checkNavItems();
    });

    checkNavItems(); 
});
```

Bear in mind, I can't really test it. If you had sample markup then it would be simple to test against. Knowing me there is likely some syntax error. But you get the idea.